# How to move an image inside canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

How to move an image inside a canvas shape or stroke. Example like http://www.case-3d.com/. Is there any tutorial how to create that example. Thnx

Comment: there are loads of tutorial regarding canvas. did you take the effort to look for them before you asked this question?

Comment: i'm newby in canvas but i must do something like this example on one of my websites. I have create a stroke and fill stroke with img. But i need to move the img inside that canvas. How can i do that ?

Comment: have you seen my original question?

Answer (score 0):

the basic idea.

clear the canvas (use context.clearRect(x,y,w,h))

-> draw it again on different place.